# Turn table attributes into a constant

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying for a few hours to wrap my head around this, and I am not sure if it is possible. I am currently working on a few triggers for a database, and one of them states that in  a specific table, only one attribute can be modified. The rest cant be changed after the original input.

Is this actually possible ?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle this is quite easy, I do this all the time. I have many tables with a CREATED_DT, CREATED_BY column that I only want set when the record is created. MODIFIED_DT, MODIFIED_BY are set with each change to the record. The trigger appears as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myschema.BILLING_SUMMARY_CHARGE_TRG
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON myschema.billing_summary_charge
   REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.modified_dt   := SYSDATE;
   :new.modified_by   := USER;

   IF INSERTING
   THEN
      :new.i_charge_pk   := billing_summary_charge_seq_pk.NEXTVAL;
      :new.created_dt    := :new.modified_dt;
      :new.created_by    := :new.modified_by;
   END IF;

   -- Don't allow creation columns to change on an update
   IF UPDATING
   THEN
      :new.i_charge_pk   := :old.i_charge_pk;
      :new.created_dt    := :old.created_dt;
      :new.created_by    := :old.created_by;
   END IF;
END billing_summary_charge_trg;
```

In the above example, columns i_charge_pk, created_dt, and created_by are initialized when the record is inserted. They are assigned their old values when the record is updated, preventing any possible changes by the application.